# Hesitation to accelerate under load

Tags: toyota, corolla, acceleration, hesitation, throttle-position-sensor

Hi  I have recently started getting some problems when accelerating from slow speeds under load. For example, I am driving up a hill behind a slow truck, when I am ready to accelerate the car hesitates and jerks up. I changed the spark plugs, coil packs, clean injectors and replaced the fuel pump and filter. Nothing helped. The most amount of improvement I got was when I replaced the air filter in that the issue happens fewer timed. So I am thinking it has something to do with the amount of air entering the engine, so I cleaned the Mass air flow sensor, no improvements. Now I tried testing my TPS sensor, and it increases and decreases smoothly. The only thing I found weird was that at full throttle, I got a reading of 3.88V but the supppy to the TPS is 5V. Could this be a issue? Also at idle I got 0.55V. This is for a Toyota Corolla Nze 121.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!